# Can't convert jsbin demo into fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it sounds weird but this demo http://jsbin.com/ixUzURUB/1/edit I can't convert it into http://jsfiddle.net/jhb2L/ What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

Comment: Seems to be a bug in jsFiddle, as even though you're adding the `jsapi` as a External Resource, it isn't been loaded on the page.

Comment: The bug seems to be that if a resources doesn't end in .js it won't load. You can get around it by adding a bogus querystring with a value that ends in .js it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSFiddle have problems when you add external resources that doesn't end in .js it seems. Added a ?fake=.js to the path and it worked. Also removed the `window.onload = function() {};` that JSFiddle adds and now it seems to be working.

http://jsfiddle.net/jhb2L/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting this code it should work :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>

<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: just remove them .. anyway it should work with tags AND without tags

Comment: Yup, it works if the script tag is in the body. The external resources feature doesn't seem to work in this case, for whatever reason. http://jsfiddle.net/jhb2L/1/